# Windows 10 boots to purple screen with broken diagonal lines from grub menu after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, windows-10, grub-legacy

I installed 18.04 having already Windows 10 in the system. I had set Windows 10 on recovery mode, installed Ubuntu, then this happened when I came back to deactivate recovery mode.

[image: Windows 10 boots to purple screen]

BIOS is on Legacy Support, not Secure Boot, as Windows 10 wouldn't boot without activating Legacy mode. Can I fix this from Ubuntu or should I uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into Ubuntu by selecting it from the GRUB menu (GRUB menu screenshot in step 4).
2. Open the terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l`
3. Restart your system with `sudo reboot`
4. Select Windows 10 from the GRUB boot menu.

   [image]
5. It may boot into safe mode.
6. In Windows 10 Start menu type *System Configuration* -> select *Boot* tab -> uncheck *Safe boot* -> click *Apply* button -> click *OK* button.

   [image]
7. Reboot again with `sudo reboot`.